# Deriving Properties of Markov Chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I had the following question about **Discrete Time Markov Chains.**

Suppose we define a Discrete Time Markov Chain as a Stochastic Process ${X_n : n = 0, 1, 2, ...}$ such that for any set of states $i_0, i_1, ..., i_{n+1}$ and any time step $t > s$, the probability of being in state $i_{n+1}$ at time $t$ given the history of the process up to  time $s$ only depends on the state $i_n$ at time $s$ is:

$$ P(X_t = i_{n+1} | X_s = i_s, X_{s-1} = i_{s-1}, ..., X_0 = i_0) = P(X_t = i_{n+1} | X_s = i_n) $$

where $P(X_t = i | X_s = j)$ is the probability of the process being in state $i$ at time $t$ given that it was in state $j$ at time $s$.

For simplicity sake, lets say that this Markov Chain is time-homogeneous - for any states $i$ and $j$, the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ at time $t$ only depends on the states $i$ and $j$:

$$ P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i) = P_{ij} $$

where $P_{ij}$ denotes the transition probability from state $i$ to state $j$. For this Markov Chain, we can define the corresponding transition matrix like this :

$$ P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{11} & P_{12} & \cdots & P_{1n} \\
P_{21} & P_{22} & \cdots & P_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
P_{n1} & P_{n2} & \cdots & P_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where :

- $P_{ij} = \frac{n_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^n n_{ik}}$ and $n_{ij}$ is the frequency of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ in the observed data.
- All entries of $P$ are nonnegative: $P_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i,j$.
- The row sums of $P$ are equal to 1: $\sum_{j=1}^m P_{ij} = 1$ for all $i$.

**My Question:** For a long time, I have been interested in learning about how to calculate properties about these transition probabilities $P_{ij}$ - for example, suppose we have observe some data and fit a Discrete Time Markov Chain to this data (i.e. estimate the transition probabilities), **how do we then find out the Variance and Confidence Intervals** for $\hat{P}_{ij}$ (e.g. the estimate of $P_{ij}$)?

Using logic, I think that $\hat{P}_{ij}$ are like "dice rolls" - if you have rolled a number $i$, what is the probability of rolling some other number $j$ out of a total of $n$ possible numbers? If this is the case, this reminds me of the Multinomial Probability Distribution:

$$ P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ..., X_k = x_k) = \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_k!} p_1^{x_1} p_2^{x_2} ... p_k^{x_k} $$

where:

- There are $k$ possible outcomes with probabilities $p_1, p_2, ..., p_k$
- And $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ are the number of times each outcome occurs in $n$ trials
- And  $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = n$ and $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k$.

As the Multinomial Distribution is a well-studied distribution, we know that:

- The Mean is  $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = n p_i$
- The Variance is $\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = n p_i (1 - p_i)$.

**Thus, if I were to extend this logic to Markov Chains, I would conclude that the 95% Confidence Interval for any given $\hat{P}_{ij}$ (using the Wald Confidence Interval) can be given by**:

$$ \text{95% CI for } \hat{p}_{ij} = \hat{p}_{ij} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}_{ij}\cdot (1-\hat{p}_{ij})}{n_{i}}} $$

Where :

- $\hat{p}_{ij}$ is the estimate (e.g. Maximum Likelihood Estimate) of $P_{ij}$
- $n_{i}$ is the number of times the Markov Chain left "state i"

**I am not sure if my logic is correct - can someone please tell me if I am correctly applying the mathematical logic here?**

Thanks!

**Additional References:**

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/vignettes/an_introduction_to_markovchain_package.pdf (e.g. page 31 - links to several other references are contained within this reference )

Comment: Are you asking how to estimate p_ij from experiments?

Comment: @ Whosit: thank you for your reply! I am asking how do we theoretically determine the behavior of p_ij in general

Comment: Theoretically $P_{ij}$ are known constants, confidence intervals make sense only where there are unknown constants which we want to estimate from experiments (with random noise)

Comment: @ whoisot: thank you for your reply! yes, I agree - but we should still be able to find out how their estimator varries?

Comment: btw i fixed the link formatting here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646696/proving-markov-property-in-a-continuous-time-markov-chains

Comment: Remember in the time homogeneous setting, $P_{i,j}$ is a matrix of constants. Therefore, we don’t need any estimators. It’s like trying to find an estimator for the mean when you already know that the mean is $1$. It only makes sense if the entries are unknown for you to produce confidence intervals

Comment: @  FD_bfa: thank you for your reply! great point! I guess in real world applications where you want to estimate Pij based on some data, you might need to calculate the variances. I am trying to understand the theoretical derivation for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is completely correct, with some minor mathematical incompleteness, part of which involves assumptions on your chain, namely that it is irreducible and finite.

You propose a common-sense estimator for $p_{i,j}$, namely $\hat{p}_{i,j} = N_{i,j} / N_i$. This is in fact the maximum likelihood estimator (see links below). The key to concluding your calculation is to observe that you want to compute the variance of your *estimator* conditioned on $N_i$, that is:
\begin{align*}\mathrm{Var}(\hat{p}_{i,j} | N_i = n_i) &= \mathrm{Var}\left( \frac{N_{i,j}}{N_i} \bigg | N_i = n_i \right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{n_i^2} \mathrm{Var}(N_{i,j} | N_i = n_i) \\
&= \frac{1}{n_i^2} n_i p_{i,j} ( 1- p_{i,j}).
\end{align*}
I did this explicitly, even though you already did, because I wanted to be clear about where the factor of $n_i$ in the denominator comes from.

Conditional probabilities can be tricky and some mathematical rigor is required, but one cannot abandon common sense entirely. As you say, in real life, you *know* how many times you visited $n_i$ (at least for the simple, finite state space models in which you know all the states that you consider here). A key observation is that each time you are at $i$, you have a new chance to move to any $j$, completely independently of everything that happened in the past. In other words, for each state $i$, you have independent and identically distributed samples from a multinomial distribution. This is a consequence of the (strong) Markov property.

So, you can pretend you have no idea about the Markov chain, and that you are observing exits from a specific state $i$, which you have $n_i$ of. It follows that indeed,
$$\frac{\hat{p}_{i,j} - p_{i,j}}{\sqrt{p_{i,j}(1-p_{i,j})/n_i}} \Rightarrow N(0, 1)$$
as $n_i \rightarrow \infty$, where $\Rightarrow$ denotes convergence in distribution (see for instance Proposition 6.3 part 2. [in these notes](http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/18A_stat516/Lec6_MC_Inf.pdf)). It can also be shown that $N\pi_i / N_i \rightarrow 1$ almost surely, where $N$ is the total number of moves of the chain and $\pi_i$ is the stationary distribution of the chain. You can put confidence intervals as you said.

There are also plenty of references on this on the web:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77727/confidence-intervals-for-transition-probabilities-between-known-discrete-states (where you even commented)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14360/estimating-markov-chain-probabilities
- [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf)

Since you commented on stats stackexchange question back in December 2022, and have asked a similar question again, is there something else that needs to be clarified?

Edit:

To clarify some of the discussion in the comments, I attach a little example. Consider the following Markov chain.

[image]

Suppose that $p_{0,2} = 0$, $p_{1,2} = \varepsilon \ll 1$, so that it takes many steps to get to state 2 starting from 0 or 1. @Adam points out that the notes [I linked above](http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/18A_stat516/Lec6_MC_Inf.pdf) take care to establish a Central Limit Theorem with $N$ denoting the number of steps of the whole Markov Chain (see the use of Anscombe's lemma). To use the form of the CLT described in the notes, one must justify the approximation $N_i \approx N\pi_i$, where $\pi$ denotes the stationary distribution.

But this isn't necessary if you just want to put confidence intervals on, say, $\hat{p}_{0,0}$. In fact, you can put confidence intervals on $\hat{p}_{0,0}$ without ever having visited state 2! Given $N_0$ visits to $0$, you can apply the classical CLT to just the i.i.d. sequence of transitions $T_k = 1_{\{(0,0)\}}(X_{\tau_k}, X_{\tau_k+1})$, $k=0, \dots, N_0-1$. Notice that I make no claims about $\hat{p}_0$, the probability of being at 0.

Here's a quick and dirty implementation of this in Python. Caveat emptor: I scribbled this code very quickly, so there may be mistakes. I'm also applying an "engineer's" version of error bars, i.e. $\pm 2\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

[image]

```
eps = 1e-30
# define the transition matrix with epsilon
# so small that we never visit 2
P = np.array(
    [[0.3, 0.7, 0],
     [0.6, 0.4-eps, eps],
     [0, eps, 1-eps]])

# simulate the chain
n = 10000
X = [0]
for i in range(n):
    new_x = np.random.choice([0,1,2], p=P[X[-1]])
    X.append(new_x)
X = np.array(X)

# get the number of transitions to 0, starting from 0
at_0 = X[:-1] == 0
transition_00 = (X[:-1] == 0) & (X[1:] == 0)
N_00 = transition_00[at_0]
N_0 = np.arange(len(N_00))+1

# estimate \hat{p}, and get the variance, p_00 * (1 - p_00) ~= 0.3 * 0.7. 
p_00 = np.cumsum(N_00) / N_0
sigma = sum(N_00) / (N_0[-1]-1) - p_00[-1]**2

plt.plot(N_0, p_00)
plt.fill_between(N_0, p_00[-1] + 2*sigma/np.sqrt(N_0), p_00[-1] - 2*sigma/np.sqrt(N_0), alpha=0.3)
plt.xlabel('# times at 0', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(r"$\hat{p}_{0,0}$", fontsize=20)
plt.axis([100, len(N_0), 0.2, 0.4])
```

Is this method optimal? Possibly not. Are the error bars meaningful? Yes.

I suppose the final thing to address in this story is: if I'm making error bars for transition probabilities look so simple, why is this so hard in practical problems involving, say, MCMC? One reason is that in hard sampling problems, you don't even know all the states, you don't quite know which states you transition to, and you certainly don't know if the part of the Markov chain you're exploring is where the action is, or if there is some distant part of the chain (such as state 2) that holds more overall mass (as measured by $\pi$) that is as of yet unexplored. The inability to quantify the unexplored $\pi$-volume is in a sense *the* insurmountable problem of sampling.

Comment: While your conclusion is true, as argued in the linked notes, your argument isn't quite right. Asymptotically, yes, we can assume $Var[N_{i,j}\mid N_i=n_i] = n_i p_{i,j}(1-p_{i,j})$, but this is not an equality for finite samples. For example, if $X_0 = 0$, $p_{0,0}=\tfrac12$, $n=2$, then $Var[N_{0,0}\mid N_0=2] = \tfrac14 < \tfrac12 = n_ip_{i,i}(1-p_{i,i})$.

Comment: The expression for the conditional variance of $N_{i,j}$ given $N_i = n_i$ is a strict equality for any $n_i \geq 0$. You can see this by considering the stopped sequence $X_{\tau_1+1}, X_{\tau_2+1}, ..., \dots X_{\tau_{n_i}+1}$, where $\tau_k$ is the $k^{th}$ return time to $i$, and using the strong Markov property. Where did you get $\mathrm{Var}(N_{0,0}|N_0=2) = 1/4$ from? Also, it might be good to undelete your post for clarity for the OP.

Comment: If $n=2$, conditional on $N_0=2$, we must have observed $X_0 = X_1 = 0$, and $P(X_2 = 0) = \tfrac12$. Hence $N_{0,0}$ is either $1$ or $2$, each with probability $\tfrac12$, and its variance is $\tfrac14$. The Markov property doesn't help, because $N_i = n_i$ contains future information.

Comment: (I'm happy to just refer to your linked notes on this, but if you think anything else is needed from my answer, feel free to add it to yours.)

Comment: You are still missing the point. It is false that if $N_0 = 2$, we must have observed $X_0 = X_1 = 0$. What is true is that $X_{\tau_0} = X_{\tau_1} = 0$, where $\tau_0 = 0$ and $\tau_1$ is the first return time to $0$, and $\tau_1 \leq N$, where $N$ is the total number of steps. Note that $N_i = \sum_{n=0}^N 1_{\{i\}}(X_n)$ (or sum up to $N-1$, depending on convention), so indeed $N$ could be far, far greater than $N_i$. Maybe $N=1000$, $X_0 = 0$ and $X_{999} = 0$, but $X_n \neq 0$ for any $0 < n < 999$.

Comment: If $N_0 = 2$, *and also* $n=2$, then it is true that $X_0 = X_1 = 0$. The variable $N_0 = \sum_{k=0}^1 1(X_k=0);$ the only way for it to equal $2$ is if both $X_0$ and $X_1$ are zero. If your statistical model was that you observe your chain until you've hit $0$ twice, then yes, your version would be correct, but you can't do that for all states $i$ simultaneously; your sample size doesn't get to change with $i$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't believe me, consider the notes you linked to. They go to some effort to account for this effect, and do not just declare everything conditionally binomial. Why?

Comment: @Adam, I updated my post. If you still disagree, please let me know where my use of the classical CLT is wrong.

Comment: @ Snar: WOW! thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: I am a bit confused about two relations you wrote:

Comment: Relation 1: N_i = N_pi_i

Comment: Relation 2: N_i /  N_pi_i = 1

Comment: Can you please explain these a bit more?  Thank you so much!

Comment: If the chain is finite, irreducible and aperiodic, then it "mixes" well. In particular, the proportion of time you are at state $i$ is proportional to $\pi_i$, where $\pi$ is the stationary vector $\pi^T P = \pi^T$. @stats_noob are you familiar with the concept of a stationary distribution?

Comment: @snar I still think you're hiding a lot in the statement "Given $N_0$ visits to $0$." Are you saying that you sampled the chain until you hit $0$ for the $N_0$th time, then stopped? Or that you ran your chain for $N$ total samples, and happened to observe $N_0$ visits to $0$? These really are different things, and you can't just fudge between them. The former works as you say, but only for one state, and only if you really did sample that way; the latter requires something like Anscombe's Lemma, as the variables you're applying the CLT to are not iid, after conditioning on $N_0$.

Comment: The point of using Anscombe's Lemma is that it turns the latter into the former; asymptotically, the latter behaves *as if* you visited each state a predetermined number of times, and hence you can argue the way you want to. But this result has to be proved, and is merely asymptotic, not finite-time. So yes, your error bars are meaningful, but not for the reason you claim.

Answer (score 1):

See [1], where this and related problems are discussed for reversible Markov chains, and [2] for a follow-up in the non-reversible case.

[1] Hsu, Daniel, Aryeh Kontorovich, David A. Levin, Yuval Peres, Csaba Szepesvári, and Geoffrey Wolfer. "Mixing time estimation in reversible markov chains from a single sample path." Annals of Applied Probability 29, no. 4 (2019): 2439-2480.  https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-29/issue-4/Mixing-time-estimation-in-reversible-Markov-chains-from-a-single/10.1214/18-AAP1457.pdf

[2] Wolfer, Geoffrey, and Aryeh Kontorovich. "Estimating the mixing time of ergodic markov chains." In Conference on Learning Theory, pp. 3120-3159. PMLR, 2019.

Comment: @ Yuval Peres: Thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, could you please write the main points and show the formula? thank you so much!